# embed heroku app on my website

Tags: heroku, web, pandorabots

I have a pandorabot that is deployed via Heroku (it could be any other app for that matter). I'm not very familiar with Heroku and I'm now trying to find a way to integrated this Heroku-deployed app on my website (as a popup, a page or whatever for a first POC).

Do you have any pointer that would help me on this matter ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I embedded my bot using an iframe (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) . So you're essentially embedding a webpage within a webpage.